# How to store class into android listview?

Tags: java, android, listview, listactivity

This is a simple listview example

```
public class Test extends ListActivity {
    ArrayList<String> txt;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        txt=new ArrayList<String>();
        txt.add("diaplay text 1");
        txt.add("diaplay text 2");
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, txt));
    }
}
```

But this can only store string

I want do something like this

```
<ul>
    <li data-meta="hidden text 1">display text 1</li>
    <li data-meta="hidden text 2">display text 2</li>
</ul>
```

Because I want store more information in each list item

So I want store this class into listview

```
public class Item
{
    public String displayText;
    public String meta;
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You have to implement your custom adapter, extending `BaseAdapter`.

Comment: @bigdestroyer add your comment as answer that will be better way

Comment: You should show us the layout which represents the way you want to display the information on the `ListView`.

Comment: FYI: Always add a tag for the language you are using, otherwise the syntax highlighting will not work properly.

Comment: Is your issue solved or do you need further assistance? Please don't forget to accept and/or upvote the answers which helped you most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement a custom `Adapter` for that. First we have to fix your view model, you call it `Item`:

```
public class Item
{
    public String displayText;
    public String meta;
}
```

Those fields should be private with appropriate getters and setters and constructors. If you want to modify such `Items` in a `List` you also need to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`. If you do all that your `Item` class should look something like this:

```
public class Item {
    private String displayText;
    private String meta;

    public Item(String displayText, String meta) {
        this.displayText = displayText;
        this.meta = meta;
    }

    public Item() {
    }

    public String getDisplayText() {
        return displayText;
    }

    public void setDisplayText(String displayText) {
        this.displayText = displayText;
    }

    public String getMeta() {
        return meta;
    }

    public void setMeta(String meta) {
        this.meta = meta;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Item item = (Item) o;

        if (displayText != null ? !displayText.equals(item.displayText) : item.displayText != null) return false;
        return !(meta != null ? !meta.equals(item.meta) : item.meta != null);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = displayText != null ? displayText.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (meta != null ? meta.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now we need to create a layout for the `Items` in the `ListView`, for example something simple like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rlRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_background">

    <TextView
        style="@style/DefaultTextView"
        android:id="@+id/tvDisplayText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/DefaultTextView"
        android:id="@+id/tvMeta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tvDisplayText"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/tvDisplayText"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In this layout we have two `TextViews` to display both the `Strings` from each `Item`. To increase `ListView` performance you should always implement the view holder pattern. For this purpose we create a `ViewHolder` class. Its purpose is to hold a reference to the relevant `Views` in each row of the `ListView` so we don't have to perform the expensive `findViewById()` as often:

```
public class ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvDisplayText;
    public TextView tvMeta;
}
```

Note that we don't need getters and setters or anything in this view holder. We will access the public fields directly.

Now we can implement our custom `Adapter`. This is actually pretty straight forward, I will comment the most important parts.

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final List<Item> items;

    private ExampleAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items) {
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Item getItem(int position) {
        return this.items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return this.items.get(position).hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final Item item = getItem(position);

        if(convertView == null) {
            // If convertView is null we have to inflate a new layout
            convertView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_list_item, parent, false);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.tvDisplayText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDisplayText);
            viewHolder.tvMeta = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMeta);

            // We set the view holder as tag of the convertView so we can access the view holder later on.
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        // Retrieve the view holder from the convertView
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        // Bind the values to the views
        viewHolder.tvDisplayText.setText(item.getDisplayText());
        viewHolder.tvMeta.setText(item.getMeta());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And you would use this custom `Adapter` like this:

```
final List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
items.add(new Item("a", "b"));
items.add(new Item("c", "d"));
items.add(new Item("e", "f"));
items.add(new Item("g", "h"));

final ExampleAdapter adapter = new ExampleAdapter(context, items);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Can I use custom Adapter without using the custom layout? Because I am not going to create a special listview, the default layout is suitable, I just want to display one text in the listview, the other data is just for programming purpose. When I retrieve object from click event, I can easier get the meta data without matching two separated string arrays by position. If I use default layout, how to  implement the getView method? I don't know how the default adapter is implemented.

Comment: Sure you can, just use one of the default layouts like  `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`.

Answer (score 1):

You have implementation BaseAdapter, ArrayApdater or somethings.

In your adapter you pass a list of custom objects.

Here a sample code:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Item> items;

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Item> items) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return items.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null);


        Item item = items.get(position);

        //Setter text

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Tutorial:

- [BaseAdapter](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)
- [Official Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html)

Comment: A few things that caught my eye: Why are you passing an `Activity` instance to the `Adapter`? Seems weird, normally you should only pass a `Context` to the `Adapter`. Also why are you creating the `LayoutInflater` in `getView()`? It is much better to create it in the constructor, if possible final. And you should also use `LayoutInflater.from(context)` instead of `(LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)`

Answer (score 0):

To store custom data in a ListView adapter, you must implement your own. Take a look at [Custom `BaseAdapter` with `ListView`](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know clearly understand your question. But i understand that. Hope for help.
**strings.xml**

```
<string-array name="li_items">
    <item >Home</item>
    <item >Find People</item>
    <item >Photos</item>
    <item >Communities</item>
    <item >Pages</item>
</string-array>
```

**In your ListActivity**

```
public class Test extends ListActivity {
ArrayList<String> txt;
private String[] liItem;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    liItem= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.li_items);
    txt=new ArrayList<String>();
    txt.add(liItem[0]);
    txt.add(liItem[1]);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, txt));
}
```

}